# 特殊機能キーの自前処理

Tags: c++, windows

Fnキーを押しながらファンクションキーを押すなどして、音量の変更や輝度の変更をできる機種がありますが、これらのキー操作をフックして、自分のアプリケーションで利用することは可能でしょうか？

とりあえずWindows環境を想定しています。使用可能言語はC++です。もしOSの設定だけで機能キーを無効化させることができればそれでも良いです。

[image: 機能キー]

あとひとつ、やりたいことは基本的に同じで、Bluetooth接続のスマホ用カメラシャッターボタンを押すと、VolumeUpのキーコードが送られてきて、これを自分のアプリで捕捉することはできたのですが、OSのボリューム変更機能も一緒に動作してしまいます。これを無効化させる方法がわかりませんでした。

もともと、後者の疑問が先で、その派生の質問が前者です。特殊機能キーが押されたことは感知したいので、キーコードが送られてきたら、自分のアプリで処理したいです。しかし、OSにその機能を処理させたくないです。OSの設定でもアプリ側でキー操作をフックするのでもいいです。何か方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: Fn キーに関しては統一仕様が無いのが現状で BIOS/UEFI/OS によらずハードウエアで処理されちゃっていることが多い＝ OS 側でなにかすることは困難・不可能っす。一部メーカーではできるものもあるらしい？　ですけど。

Comment: 質問はFnキーそのものの制御ではなく、組み合わせによって得られる[VK_VOLUME_UP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)等の制御でよろしいでしょうか？ また、アプリケーションにフォーカスがある状態での制御か、それともフォーカス外でも同様に制御したいか、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: はい。Fnキーは重要ではなくて、自作アプリでキーコードが取得できればそれでいいです。ただし、それをOSに処理させたくありません。アプリにフォーカスがないときは、キーコードは取得できなくても良いですが、それでも、OSに処理させたくありません。

Comment: この辺の記事が関連のものでしょうか。[ファンクションキーの設定方法は？簡単なものからBIOSの変更も詳しく解説！](https://kuraneo.jp/posts/480), [ノートパソコンに搭載されているマルチメディアキーボード](https://www.dell.com/community/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/General-laptops-jp/message-id/515/print-single-message/false/page/1), [HP製ノートブックコンピューター - fn (ファンクション) キーをロックまたはロック解除するには](https://support.hp.com/jp-ja/document/c04094128), [F Lock 機能について教えてください。](https://www.fmworld.net/cs/azbyclub/qanavi/jsp/qacontents.jsp?PID=3711-1909)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。でもダメそうです。メーカー毎に設定方法が統一されていないのと、Fnの押下状態によって、ファンクションキー優先だったり、マルチメディアキー優先だったり、統一されていないのと、そもそも私が抱えてる問題が、ノートPCのキーボードではなくて、Bluetooth接続のスマホ用カメラシャッターボタンから送られてくるVolumeUpキーコードをOSに処理させない方法なので、なんか難しそうです。

Comment: まだ試していませんが、WM_APPCOMMANDをグローバルフックすればいいのかな？ 連休中に試してみたいと思います。

Comment: もしかしたらこれらの記事の情報が使えるかも。[how to Disable special keyboard keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38617282/9014308), [Human Interface Device Service サービスの概要と起動の必要性](http://tooljp.com/Windows10/doc/Service/Human_Interface_Device_Service.html)